Is there a way to save or retrieve weights of a neural network while it is training?
I launched my training script for 2 days, but I forgot to save the weights file for the model checkpoints. Is it possible to retrive the weights in some way without having to restart training? Such as a callback or something. I am running on private GPU server.
I plotted results during training and they look promising, but I need the weights of the network.
